# Add key in python dict, but rename if it exists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple script:

```
d = {}

keys = ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f']

for k in keys:
    if k in d:
        k += '_copy'
        
    d[k] = 'test'
    
print(d)
```

And it produce output like this:

```
{'f': 'test', 'f_copy': 'test'}
```

but I need to rename key by adding suffix

> _copy

every time I add key that already exists. So output should be something like this:

```
{'f': 'test', 'f_copy': 'test', 'f_copy_copy': 'test', 'f_copy_copy_copy': 'test'}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `while k in d` instead of `if k in d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is exactly what you want to do, but the above can be simplified by using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate

keys = ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f']
d = dict.fromkeys(accumulate(keys, lambda i,_: i+'_copy'), 'test')

print(d)
{'f': 'test',
 'f_copy': 'test',
 'f_copy_copy': 'test',
 'f_copy_copy_copy': 'test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop resets `k` each iteration of the loop to the corresponding value of `keys`. You could count the number of iterations and create the new key:

```
d = {}
keys = ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f']

for i, k in enumerate(keys):
    if k in d:
        k = f"f{i*'_copy'}"
    d[k] = 'test'
print(d)
```

Out:

```
{'f': 'test', 'f_copy': 'test', 'f_copy_copy': 'test', 'f_copy_copy_copy': 'test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
d = {}

keys = ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f']

d_count={i:0 for i in set(keys)}

for k in keys:
    m=k
    k+=d_count[k]*'_copy'
    d_count[m]+=1   
    d[k] = 'test'

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'f': 'test', 'f_copy': 'test', 'f_copy_copy': 'test', 'f_copy_copy_copy': 'test'}
```